Extending an automorphism of the residue field to an automorphism of the local ring.
Let $R$ be a commutative local ring with unity, and let $I$ be its maximal ideal.
Suppose there exists a ring automorphism $g: R/I \to R/I$.
Can we find a ring automorphism $f: R \to R$ such that the following diagram commutes?
$$g \circ \pi_{I} = \pi_{I} \circ f,$$
where $\pi_{I}$ is the natural projection map $R \to R/I$.
Request:
Can someone assist me in proving or disproving the above statement?

Have you looked at an example before asking?

Yes, I’ve tried a few examples. However, for most of the local rings I’m familiar with, the situation is quite straightforward. For instance, if we consider $Z_{\mathfrak{p}}$, the only homomorphism $R/I$ to itself is the trivial one. Similarly, for the case of $k[[X]]$ where $k$ is a field, the only automorphism of $R/I$ is derived from the automorphisms of the field $k$. These automorphisms can be easily extended to the automorphisms of $k[[X]]$.

Alright. I asked because on this site many people ask questions without putting any effort in solving these themselves, and these questions get closed quite often. Your question is different, obviously. But to prevent it from being closed or downvoted, it is recommended to always add your own progress to the post itself. See also here for more tips.

I think $R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ for $R=\mathbb{Z}[T]$, $\mathfrak{m} = \langle p , f \rangle$, where $f \in \mathbb{Z}[T]$ is irreducible mod $p$ of degree $n>1$, will be a counterexample. You cannot lift the Frobenius, right? I have no proof for now, hence this is just a comment.

Martin's example should work for most choices of $f$: If $\phi$ is an automorphism that lifts Frobenius, then $\phi(T)=aT+b$ and $aT+b-T^p\in I$, so for example just choose $f$ with degree $>p$. (Note it doesn't work for all choices, e.g. if $f=T^p-T-a$ with $p\nmid a$)

Thank you, @MartinBrandenburg, for providing a counter-example; it’s very helpful.

Thank you for your insightful comment, @leoli1.

@leoli1 Do you want to post this as an answer then?
